# Undefined function or variable in Matlab R2012a

Tags: matlab, function

I am making a small function in matlab when i write on command window error comes

```
function adding

> a=2;
b=3;
c=a+b
end
```

when i write on command window error comes

```
>> adding
```

Undefined function or variable 'adding'.

Need help.

Comment: Is the function on your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a function you should save it in a .m file with the same name as the function (`adding.m` in this case). You then have to make sure that `adding.m` is on your path; this includes being in your current working directory.

You can use the Set Path button in the Environment section of the Home menu (assuming you're using a recent ribbon style Matlab). In your case I think you'll need to click Add Folder, then browse to your My Documents folder. Then Save and Close the Set Path dialog.

You may also want to consider a function more like this:

```
function c = adding( a, b )
   c = a + b;
end
```

Comment: I already did that then save in My Documents folder , Should I want to save some where else???

Comment: You can save the file wherever you'd like, but that location has to be on the Matlab path. I'll add some detail to my answer.

Comment: I think my problem is the location .